# convert Gmt timezone to CET in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, timezone

I want to convert GMT +530 to CET (Central European Time) in iPhone sdk?
does anybody have idea about this? also tell me what is the time difference between these two?
Means if time is 10 am in gmt +530 then what it will be in CET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CET is GMT + 1 hour.  See [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cet.html).

For working with time (and dates) on the iPhone, you should start by reading Apple's [Introduction to Date and Time Programming for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html), which is part of the iPhone Developer Library.  There is a section of that document specifically on [Using Time Zones](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID).

There's a code example in the answer to a similar question here on StackOverflow: [NSDate - Convert Date to GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt/1863042#1863042)