# retaining the time zone in NSDateFormatter

Tags: cocoa, timezone, nsdateformatter

I have to set a format string for a `DateFormatter` to convert a `NSString` to a `NSDate`.

The string is in the format: `2011-01-31 12:45:00 +0200` (y-m-d h:m:s timezone)

I'm using the format: `@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'Z"` , but the timezone is converted to +0000 and the hour is adjusted, so a string like:
`2011-01-31 12:45:00 +0200` is converted to:
2011-01-31 10:45:00 +0000

The Code is here:

```
- (NSDate *) dateForString: (NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale;
    NSDate  *date;

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];

    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'Z"];
    // [dateFormatter  setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely expected behaviour when using NSDate - NSDate represents a moment in time so in your case the 2 date/times are equivalent.

Just make sure when you display the date using the a dateFormatter you set the timezone on the date formatter to how you want it displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `setTimeZone:` in
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Some more info can also be found here:
[NSDate - Convert Date to GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt) (maybe duplicate?)