# NSDate from string

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a string "2012-09-16 23:59:59 JST"
I want to convert this date string into NSDate.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *capturedStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2012-09-16 23:59:59 JST"];
NSLog(@"%@", capturedStartDate);
```

But it is not working. Its giving null value. Please help..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When using 24 hour time, the hours specifier needs to be a capital H like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Check here for the correct specifiers : http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

However, you need to set the locale for the date formatter:

```
// Set the locale as needed in the formatter (this example uses Japanese)
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"]];
```

Full working code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"]];
NSDate *capturedStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2012-09-16 23:59:59 JST"];
NSLog(@"Captured Date %@", [capturedStartDate description]);
```

Outputs (In GMT):

```
Captured Date 2012-09-16 14:59:59 +0000
```

Comment: hey @danielbeard , as u said it will display the time GMT, which will show time difference of 9 hours from the exact date. How to get the exact date from the string.. ??..

Comment: Dates themselves don't have timezones, but you can get a string representation in a time zone with the `stringFromDate` with the NSDateFormatter set up above.

Comment: See here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt

Answer (score 6):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *capturedStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2012-09-16 23:59:59 GMT-08:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", capturedStartDate);
```

Comment: This might be useful to someone someday:  Keen.io timestamp format
`[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];`  I did not need to set the locale.

Comment: The answer was useful to me today ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 // end
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```