# change NSDate from one time zone to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Given a date in `NSString` like "2012-12-17 04:36:25" (which is GMT) how one can simply change it to other time zones like EST, CST

All the steps I saw so far took so many unnecessary steps

Comment: why were this steps unnecessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"2012-12-17 04:36:25";
NSDateFormatter* gmtDf = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[gmtDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[gmtDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* gmtDate = [gmtDf dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@",gmtDate);

NSDateFormatter* estDf = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[estDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
[estDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *estDate = [estDf dateFromString:[gmtDf stringFromDate:gmtDate]]; // you can also use str
NSLog(@"%@",estDate);
```

---

#### Edit : Adding swift code

```
let str: String = "2012-12-17 04:36:25"
let gmtDf: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
gmtDf.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
gmtDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let gmtDate: NSDate = gmtDf.dateFromString(str)!
print(gmtDate)
let estDf: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
estDf.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")
estDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let estDate: NSDate = estDf.dateFromString(gmtDf.stringFromDate(gmtDate))!
print(estDate)
```

#### Edit: Adding Swift 3 code

```
    let str: String = "2012-12-17 04:36:25"
    let gmtDf = DateFormatter()
    gmtDf.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
    gmtDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let gmtDate = gmtDf.date(from: str)!
    print(gmtDate)

    let estDf = DateFormatter()
    estDf.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")
    estDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let estDate = estDf.date(from: gmtDf.string(from: gmtDate))!
    print(estDate)
```