# NSDate change time zone

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate

I am writing an app that involves time zone. I want to grab the user's device time, lets call that `dateA`, and I have a target date that will always be in EDT time zone (`dateB`).

I want to get the difference between the 2 dates and show the user, but in `dateB`'s time zone.

eg:
user device time is 07:30AM PDT, and `dateB` is 11:00AM EDT.
So the time difference would be 30 minutes.

My algorithm is:
1) Get user device time
2) convert to EDT
3) grab the time difference between `dateA` and `dateB`

My issue is, after I get the user's device time `[NSDate date]`, and go through `DateFormatter` with timezone EDT.  The time does not change.

EDIT::

```
    NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date]; //this will have 7:30AM PDT
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EDT"]];
    NSString *convertedTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
```

How come the convertedTimeString does not contain 10:30AM in EDT?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no time zone for date, so if you form the date with proper timezone, you can calculate the difference without too many conversions.

Answer (score 2):

A `NSDate` is stored in a timezone neutral way. It's up to the `NSDateFormatter` to actually format for a given timezone using [-[NSDateFormatter setTimeZone:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setTimeZone%3a). If you want a string from `NSDate`, there's also [-[NSDate descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat%3atimeZone%3alocale%3a), but it's usually better to use a `NSDateFormatter` instead.

Comment: I saw a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917938/change-nsdate-from-one-time-zone-to-another.  Which converts the [NSDate date] into GMT and then convert my dateB into GMT as well and then calculate the time difference.  Is this an acceptable solution or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is already the solution, but it does not convert the date into GMT, it interprets the string as being a time in the GMT time zone. Take that answer and then replace `GMT` with `PDT` (this is your source time zone). Now you have a date object, _and that date object is not bound to a time zone_ (that part is important to understand: NSDate is time zone neutral). If you want to store or transmit the date, this is what you want to store or transmit. _Then_ for displaying, you again feed it to a NSDateFormatter, this time you set the target time zone and convert the date into a string.