# Time between date from string and current time in GMT

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to find the time (in minutes) between a date with the "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" format (Sample:"2014-02-03T11:28:00") and current time (In GMT, as the string is in GMT. I tried

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *trackingDataDate = [formatter dateFromString:timeStamp];

NSTimeInterval distance = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:trackingDataDate];
double timeInMinutes = distance / 60;
```

But this returns NaN. What is wrong with my code, how can I get the time between the events?

Comment: is your now trackingDataDate NSDate valid ? Set a breakpoint and validate it

Comment: Nope :D It logs null. My timestamp string is correct tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. You have miss allocation for NSDateFormatter. Add below line instead of `NSDateFormatter *formatter;`, It's working fine.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
```

**Update:** According to your comment, see my below code for convert to GMT Date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Now I get the true date, but +1 hour. How to I get NSDate date to do GMT, not system time?

Comment: @OscarApeland see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt

Comment: Nvm I fixed, found that answer myself too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString* string=@"26-01-2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"Date = %@",date);
```