# Constructing date from Int the right way

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

So i get from the backend this answer :

```
{ "SERVERDateTimeGet": { "Return Code" : 0,
    "Return String" : "No Error",
    "Year" : 2018,
        "Month" : 8,
        "Day" : 29,
        "Hour" : 14,
        "Minute" : 16,
        "Second" : 20,
        "Daylight" : 1,
        "NTP" : 0,
        "NtpDhcp" : 0,
        "NtpServers" : "time.google.com",
        "Timezone" : "EET-2EEST,M3.5.6/0:01,M9.1.5" }
 }
```

(I know this is bad ,very bad but for the time that is what i get)

I have this method :

```
func makeDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hr: Int, min: Int, sec: Int) -> Date {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
   // calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hr, minute: min, second: sec)
    //let components = DateComponents(timeZone: TimeZone.current, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hr, minute: min, second: sec)
    return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

but when i get the date it is 3 hours back.
I assume that this is because  the time zone , but as you can see i am not using the time zone.
Is there any other way to build date or just use the current ints?

Comment: What do you mean by "the date is 3 hours back"? How did you find out the difference of 3 hours? Please edit the question and provide the `makeDate` call with parameters

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on the playgrounds. Check your input to the method.

Comment: if you not set time zone it take default device timezone.

Comment: If you don't set TimeZone, that means your time will be in UTC, so you have -3 hours gap. To get the right value you need configure TimeZone. You can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt

Comment: @gaRik thanks, you were right.
i just needed to make it local time.
do you want to write that as an answer?

Comment: Do you not want to use a time zone or do you not know which time zone to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set TimeZone, that means your time will be in UTC, so you have -3 hours gap. To get the right value you need configure TimeZone. You can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862905/nsdate-convert-date-to-gmt)

Comment: That explained why i always got it 3 hour back.
i did that method from the link you gave:
      func toLocalTime() -> Date {
          let timezone = TimeZone.current
          let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
          return Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: self)
    }
 
works like a charm:)
thanks!